# How to perform login redirect with NodeJS/ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, redirect, express

I am in search of a way to redirect a user to the previous page he or she was on after successful login. For instance, if a user wants to use a feature only accessible to members, he or she would be redirected to a login page, and on a successful login, would then be redirected to what ever page the user was trying to access before being logged in. Here is what I have so far:

Middleware:

```
function requireLogin(req, res, next){
    if (!req.user) res.redirect('/login');
    else next();
}
```

Login:

```
app.post('/login', function(req,res){
    User.findOne({email: req.body.email}, function(err, user){
            if (!user) res.render('login.jade',{error: 'Invalid email or password.'});
            else{
                    if (bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password,user.password)) {
                            req.session.user = user; //set cookie session
                            res.redirect('/forums');
                    }
                    else res.render('login.jade',{error: 'Invalid email or password.'});
            }
    });
});
```

Example route:

```
app.post('/article/comment', requireLogin, function(req,res){...
```

I have seen a few SO posts about this subject, but no really qualifying answers(especially without PassportJS). Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue with a few simple additions to my existing code:

```
function requireLogin(req, res, next){
    if (!req.user) {
            req.session.prevUrl = req.body.url;
            if(req.xhr) res.send({"err":"usrErr"});
            else res.redirect('/login');
    }
    else next();
}

app.post('/login', function(req,res){
    User.findOne({email: req.body.email}, function(err, user){
            if (!user) res.render('login.jade',{error: 'Invalid email or password.'});
            else{
                    if (bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password,user.password)) {
                            req.session.user = user; //set cookie session
                            if(req.session.prevUrl) res.redirect(req.session.prevUrl);
                            else res.redirect('/forums');
                    }
                    else res.render('login.jade',{error: 'Invalid email or password.'});
            }
    });
});
```

I saved the page a user was on when trying to access a feature only available to members as session data. Note, this is a much better solution than the 'back' solution, as (for instance if the user inputs the wrong login information, the previous page will not now be the login page, but still the page saved in the session). With the session storage now saved, a simple check in the login can be done to see if the saved session url exists. If it does, redirect to the saved session url, else redirect to the default home.

P.S. The line, if(req.xhr) res.send({"err:"usrErr"}); is a check to see if the request made was a JQuery request. This is because a redirect will not be performed if the request was made through JQuery. The err response allowed me to do a simple check in my JQuery function to perform a redirect if the user did not exist. Note, the session data is still saved in this case so, simply add
window.location.href='/login'; to your function in order to perform the redirect within the script.

Thanks to @mikeyhew for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `res.redirect('back')`, the only caveat is it relies upon the `http-referer` header which is not reliable, when the `http-referer` header is omitted it defaults to `/`. Check the [docs](http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.redirect).

Comment: I considered going that route, but it seemed too unreliable for me personally. Thanks for the input though.

Comment: This inspired me to write a middleware, check out [express-back](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-back).

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you stored the request url from your `requireLogin` middleware for future use:

```
function requireLogin(req, res, next){
    if (!req.user) {
      var postLoginRedirectUrl = req.originalUrl;
      // store this url somehow (session or query params?)
      res.redirect('/login');
    } else {
      next();
    }
}
```

I've seen some sites use query params; you just have to make sure the url doesn't get lost in the login process.

Then when the user logs in successfully, just redirect them to that url.

Comment: @Nindaff the issue I see with express-back for this purpose is that if the login process involves more than one url change, the user would be redirected back into the login process. Deliberately saving the url to session in this case is more robust and future-proof.

Comment: Thanks for the input! While it was inspired by this question it really is more of a solution to `http referer` header.

Comment: As my original post indicates, I am in fact already using cookies. Perhaps something along the lines of "req.session.prevUrl=req.originalUrl"; And then in the login route, perform " if (req.session.prevUrl) res.redirect(req.session.prevUrl); else res.redirect('/dashboard')". What do you guys think?